# Отключение Hyper-V

Tags: windows, windows-10, hyper-v

Для эксперимента включил на компьютере Hyper-V, всё, что хотел, сделал и теперь нужно его отключить. В "компонентах Windows" снимаю галочку, система перезагружается, но при загрузке сообщение "Нам не удалось завершить компоненты", компьютер снова перезагружается и появляется сообщение "Нам не удалось завершить обновление". Как его все-таки отключить?

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, вопрос решился. Спасибо  Донецкому Никите [ОТСЮДА](https://answers.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/forum/windows_7-update/%D0%BD%D0%B5/d7edf66e-624f-42b4-b11a-a20c8c6467ed), который дал такой совет:

"дело в том, что винда коряво поставила обновления. скорее всего в процесе установки обновлений комп был отключен принудительно, либо сами обновления скачались криво. надо сделать так: иди сюда c:/windows/SoftwareDistribution/Download/ . удали все файлы, что находятся в папке Download.(именно в это папку винда закачивает обновления, и отсюда начинает их установку) и закачай обновления заново. после етого должно обновиться без проблем"